# Spring: How do I construct this command object through a GET HTTP request?

Tags: spring, search, command-objects

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE with Hibernate 4.0.1.Final.  I want to invoke a search method in a controller that takes as input a search bean (the Event bean below) ...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search_results.jsp")
public ModelAndView processSearch(final HttpServletRequest request, final Event searchBean, final BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```

The event bean contains the following field ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
public class Event implements Comparable {

    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="EVENT_FEED_ID")
    private EventFeed eventFeed;
    ...
}
```

in which the EventFeed object contains the following fields ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT_FEEDS")
public class EventFeed {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    ... 
}
```

How do I construct a URL such that the search bean's Event.getEventFeed().getId() field is populated?

I realize I could submit a GET request with a parameter like "eventFeedId=2" and populate everything manually, but since other pages are submitting requests that populate the command object, I'd like to continue to use the same logic.

Comment: "... populate everything manually, but since other pages are submitting requests that populate the command object" is your question: "how do I load that EventFeed from the database?" ? -- if you have an other question, can you please formulatethe question more precise: Because the answer to your formal question is `?event.eventFeed.id=1&event.eventFeed.title=hallo` - but I do not think that that is what you want to know.

Comment: Yes, "?event.eventFeed.id=1&event.eventFeed.title=hallo" is what I want to know, except as I indicated below, I tried that, and the Event.getEventFeed() bean is not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
/search_results.jsp?event.eventFeed.id=...&event.eventFeed.title=...
```

`event` is a default model attribute name as defined in [`@ModelAttribute`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html), other binding rules are described in [5.4.1 Setting and getting basic and nested properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions).

Note, however, that this approach can cause problems if you'll associate these bean with Hibernate session later. For example, if you want to attach new `Event` to the existing `EventFeed` by calling `merge()` it would also override the `title` property. Thus, in such a case it would be better to avoid overuse of data binding and pass primitives as parameters instead.

Comment: I tried the query string you suggested but the Event bean's EventFeed field is still null.